# Uploading files with spring issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file, multipart

I have this issue with my file upload/download rest api and this is the code below:
this is the service implementation\

```
package app.gym.v1.Utility.Impl;

import app.gym.v1.DAO.FileRepo;
import app.gym.v1.DAO.UserRepo;
import app.gym.v1.Model.File;
import app.gym.v1.Service.FileService;
import app.gym.v1.Utility.Exception.Domain.FileNotFoundException;
import app.gym.v1.Utility.Exception.Domain.FileStorageException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.io.IOException;

@Service
@Transactional
public class FileServiceImpl implements FileService {

//    private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private FileRepo fileRepo;
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Autowired
    public FileServiceImpl(FileRepo fileRepo, UserRepo userRepo) {
        this.fileRepo = fileRepo;
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    public File storeFile(MultipartFile file) {
        // Normalize file name
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());

        try {
            // Check if the file's name contains invalid characters
            if (fileName.contains("..")) {
                throw new FileStorageException("Sorry! Filename contains invalid path sequence " + fileName);
            }

            File dbFile = new File(fileName, file.getContentType(), file.getBytes());

            return fileRepo.save(dbFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new FileStorageException("Could not store file " + fileName + ". Please try again!", ex);
        }
    }

    public File getFile(Long id) {
        return fileRepo.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new FileNotFoundException("File not found with id " + id));
    }
}
```

this is the service file\

```
package app.gym.v1.Service;

import app.gym.v1.Model.File;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Service
public interface FileService {

    File storeFile(MultipartFile file);
    File getFile(Long id);
}
```

and this is the model entity\

```
package app.gym.v1.Model;

import app.gym.v1.Model.Domain.Gym;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "files")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class File implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "file_name")
    private String fileName;

    @Column(name = "file_type")
    private String fileType;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "data")
    private Byte[] data;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;
}
```

these are the errors:

```
/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Heroku/Gym/src/main/java/app/gym/v1/Utility/Impl/FileServiceImpl.java:41:27
java: no suitable constructor found for File(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,byte[])
    constructor app.gym.v1.Model.File.File() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor app.gym.v1.Model.File.File(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Byte[],app.gym.v1.Model.User) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

as you can see all the problems with the service implementation and I tried to change the entity content but the same problem

Comment: As message point out "there is no suitable constructor File(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,byte[])"

Comment: you mean I have to change it ??

Comment: File dbFile = new File(fileName, file.getContentType(), file.getBytes()); // how can code get compiled at this line when you have no suitable constructor

Comment: Ohhhhhh I see thanks a lot